# How can I get an email copy of completed forms?

Tags: cognito-forms

I made a form to be completed by my visited on my web page. I'd like the completed form to be sent to my email, as it will have healthcare information.

I see that the completed form is sent to `CognitoForms.com`. I need the forms sent to my email, as I really don't want another dashboard to manage.

I need to be able to print this form from the email.

Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 1):

[Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) supports sending email notifications to both [people you specify](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/20/building-forms/notification-emails) as well as [the individual who filled out the form](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/13/building-forms/confirmation-emails).  These email notifications can optionally include all form data as well as an attached printable PDF of the submitted form.

[image]

However, healthcare information falls under HIPAA and HITECH regulation in the United States and similar laws in other countries.  For this reason, we have recently implemented support for [Data Encryption](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/data-encryption), which encrypts 100% of entry data and uploaded files "at rest" and further helps you by identifying specific fields that need to be protected and not shared insecurely.

When these feature are used correctly, sensitive healthcare information may be collected safely using Cognito Forms.  However, Cognito Forms absolutely prevents insecure transmission of protected fields, so you will not be able to include them in email notifications, which can be intercepted in route.